# Convertir INPUT type checkbox a INPUT type text despues de click

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente checkbox y lo quiero cambiar a text depues del click

```
<input type="checkbox" name="nutriente_f1<? echo $registro6['ID_NUTRIENTE']; ?>" id="nutriente_f1-<? echo $registro6['ID_NUTRIENTE']; ?>" onclick="$nutriente_f1(<? echo $registro6['ID_NUTRIENTE']; ?>,<? echo $registro6['ID_NUTRIENTE']; ?>);">
```

Lo unico que quiero es cambiarle el Type a text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice un pequeño codigo, espero te sirva, lo hice con jquery y JS puro:

```js
$("#prueba").click((e) => {
  
  let attrType = $(e.target).attr("type");
  
  if(attrType === "checkbox"){
    $(e.target).attr("type","text");
  }else{
    $(e.target).prop('checked',false);
    $(e.target).attr("type","checkbox");
  }

});

var elemento = document.getElementById("prueba2");
elemento.addEventListener("click", () => {
 
  let type = elemento.getAttribute("type"); 
  if(type === "checkbox"){
    elemento.setAttribute("type","text");
  }else{
    elemento.setAttribute("type","checkbox");
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="prueba" type="checkbox">prueba 1 (Jquery)

<input id="prueba2" type="checkbox"> prueba 2 (JS PURO)
```

Comment: Esta genial, gracias
Solo que cuando regresa a checkbox sigue en checked
Se puede que al regresar se desmarque sola?

Comment: $("#prueba").click((e) => {

Aqui en la parte de prueba, se puede poner una variable??

Comment: Listo edite mi ejemplo en prueba para que cuando vuelva al checkbox este deseleccionado, y si puedes colocar una variable

Answer (score 0):

Con Javascript puedes hacerlo de esta forma:

```html
<input id="inputTest" type="checkbox" name="password" />
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('inputTest').type = 'text';
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con jQuery podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```js
$('#nutriente').on('change',function(){
    //Cambio el tipo a text
    $(this).prop('type','text');
    //Le pongo el label asociado como placeholder
    $(this).prop('placeholder', $('[for="'+$(this).prop('id')+'"]').text());
    //Escondo el label
    $('[for="'+$(this).prop('id')+'"]').css('display','none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="nutriente">Cambio al clickearme!</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="nutriente">
```