# Cambiar "Type" de un input con javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

quisiera saber si con javascript es posible poder cambiar el atributo "type" de un input `<input type="radio" name="transporte2" value="2">`, por ejemplo al seleccionar de un combobox una opción y dependiendo de ella el input puede cambiar a un tipo "texto - checkbox - select , etc". actualmente soy nuevo en ello y estuve investigando y me tope con los selectors que creo que se puede hacer usando la expresión `input[type=text]` en javascript, no se si alguien puede orientarme si es posible.

Comment: Parece ser que sí se puede pero no es lo que te recomendaría. Creo que sería mejor tener un input de cada tipo y mostrar el que corresponda cada vez o crearlos al vuelo

Comment: el atributo type lo puedes cambiar con jquery ,con la función attr y removeAttr ,suerte

Comment: Puedes guiarte de una respuesta que di similar a lo que tu quieres, allí la tienes en **js** puro y en **jquery** espero te sirva: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/196182/95526](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/196182/95526)

Comment: gracias @David, era justo lo que buscaba.

Comment: Perfecto, puedes marcar mi respuesta como correcta en el otro post? gracias @MiguelAngel